# Using the Sobolev-Nirenberg-Gagliardo inequality in a proof

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces, normed-spaces

If $1 \leq p < n$. The Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality states that there exists a  constant C such that $||u||_{L^{p^{*}}(\mathbb{R}^{n})} \leq C||Du||_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}$ for all $u \in C_{c}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

The first part of the theorem of General Sobolev Inequalities states:

Let $U$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, with a $C^{1}$ boundary. Assume $u \in W^{k,p}(U)$. If $k < \frac{n}{p}$ then $u \in L^{q}(U)$ where $\frac{1}{q} = \frac{1}{p} - \frac{k}{n}$.

At the start of proof they state:

Assume $k < \frac{n}{p}$ then since $D^{\alpha}u \in L^{p}(U)$ for all $|\alpha| = k$, the Sobolev-Nirenberg-Gagliardo inequality implies $||D^{\beta }u||_{L^{p^{*}}(U)} \leq C||u||_{W^{k,p}(U)}$ if $|\beta| = k-1$.

How do we use the Sobolev-Nirenberg-Gagliardo inequality without the assumption that $u \in C_{c}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$?

Comment: Every single Sobolev embedding theorem is proved by density: first you prove the theorem for smooth functions with compact support. Then you show that you can prove the general case by approximating a given Sobolev function with a $C_c^1$ function. I suspect that your source doesn't repeat this scheme explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. No it is not stated explicitly. Could you please expand a bit on how this scheme works? So Sobolev Inequalities are all proved for smooth functions first and then the exact same Theorem is proved for a $C_{c}^{1}$ function? Where does the $C_{c}^{1}$ functions fit in? I can understand how we can prove the Inequalities for smooth functions and then use some limit arguments to extend to the Sobolev functions but I can't see why would need to prove for $C_{c}^{1}$ functions? Thanks.

Comment: Given $v \in W^{k,p}(U)$, find a sequence of functions $u_n \in W^{k,p}(U) \cap C_c^1(\mathbb R^n)$ and $u_n \to v$ in $W^{k,p}(U)$.  Prove that $D^\beta u_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^{p^*}(U)$, and argue that the only possibility for the limit of $D^\beta u_n$ is $D^\beta v$.  For the latter, all you need to show is that there exists a subsequence that converges to $D^\beta v$.  That is generally how these arguments work.

Comment: Thanks I think I have a better idea of how the scheme works. But would I be right in stating that the Nirenberg-Gagliardo-Sobolev inequality cannot be applied directly to some arbitrary $u \in W^{k,p}$ but we should instead use the embedding theorem which follows from the Nirenberg-Gagliardo_Sobolev inequality? The Theorem is as follows: Let $U$ be bounded, open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $\partial U$ is $C^{1}$. Assume $1 \leq p < n$ and $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$. Then $u \in L^{p^{*}}(U)$, with $||u||_{L^{p^{*}}(U)} \leq C||u||_{W^{1,p}(U)}$.